# Volley API endpoints

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display Top rated movies after clicking on a Menu Item. But, I have no idea how to do it. I read something about having to implement shared preferences but I'm not too sure about that. The URLs work fine and are returning the correct information. It's the logic for displaying Top Rated Movies that I can't get right after clicking on a menu option.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
      MyMoviesAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MyMoviesAdapter myMoviesAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Movies> mMoviesList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Check for connection
        if (checkConnection()) {


            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            parseMovieJSON();

            mMoviesList = new ArrayList<>();


        } else if (!checkConnection()) {

            //show a toast message if there is no network connection

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }


        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myMoviesAdapter);


    }

    // parse Json using volley to make network call
    private void parseMovieJSON() {

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.POPULAR_URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject movie = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                //Get json data as strings
                                String posterPath = movie.optString("poster_path");
                                String originalTitle = movie.optString("title");
                                String overview = movie.getString("overview");
                                String releaseDate = movie.optString("release_date");
                                String voteAverage = movie.optString("vote_average");


                                mMoviesList.add(new Movies(posterPath, originalTitle, overview, releaseDate, voteAverage));

                            }

                            myMoviesAdapter = new MyMoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, mMoviesList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myMoviesAdapter);
                            myMoviesAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {

                    if (checkConnection()) {

                        parseMovieJSON();

                    } else if (!checkConnection()) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mMoviesList = null;

                    }


                }

            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
        checkConnection();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.most_popular:


            case R.id.top_rated:
                if (id == R.id.top_rated){
                    setTitle("TOP RATED");
                    // return Top rated Movies list from API 

                }


                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //Detail intents to throw data to Movie Detail activity for displaying.
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        Movies clickedItem = mMoviesList.get(position);

        detailIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_URL, clickedItem.getmPosterPath());
        detailIntent.putExtra(Constants.TITLE_TEXT, clickedItem.getmOriginalTitle());
        detailIntent.putExtra(Constants.OVERVIEW_TEXT, clickedItem.getmOverview());
        detailIntent.putExtra(Constants.RELEASE, clickedItem.getmReleaseDate());
        detailIntent.putExtra(Constants.VOTE_AVERAGE, clickedItem.getmVoteAverage());

        // Send the intent to launch a Movie detail activity
        startActivity(detailIntent);

    }


    // A reference to the ConnectivityManager to check state of network connectivity mobile and wifi
    private boolean checkConnection() {

        boolean wifiConnected = false;
        boolean mobileDataConnected = false;

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        assert connectivityManager != null;
        NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();

        for (NetworkInfo info : networkInfos) {
            if (info.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (info.isConnected())
                    wifiConnected = true;
            if (info.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (info.isConnected())
                    mobileDataConnected = true;

        }
        return wifiConnected || mobileDataConnected;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't set a new adapter again in network response. Use notifyDataSetChanged as shown below.

Inside onCreateMethod

```
            mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new 
            GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myMoviesAdapter);
            myMoviesAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
```

inside parseMovieJSON method

```
private void parseMovieJSON(String url) {

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

                            myMoviesList.clear()

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject movie = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                //Get json data as strings
                                String posterPath = movie.optString("poster_path");
                                String originalTitle = movie.optString("title");
                                String overview = movie.getString("overview");
                                String releaseDate = movie.optString("release_date");
                                String voteAverage = movie.optString("vote_average");


                                mMoviesList.add(new Movies(posterPath, originalTitle, overview, releaseDate, voteAverage));

                            }

                            myMoviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {

                    if (checkConnection()) {

                        parseMovieJSON();

                    } else if (!checkConnection()) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mMoviesList = null;

                    }


                }

            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
        checkConnection();

    }
```

Assuming you have a another URL to get best rated movies call parseMovieJSON method again using that URL

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.most_popular:
           parseMovieJSON(Constants. POPULAR_URL);
           break;

        case R.id.top_rated:
            setTitle("TOP RATED");
            // return Top rated Movies list from API 
            parseMovieJSON(Constants.HIGH_RATED_URL);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Although I had to set parseMovieJSON(Constants. POPULAR_URL) OnCreate because the opening activity loads Popular Movies. Also I was wondering, what role is "myMoviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" and " mMoviesList.clear() " in this sequence?

Comment: mMoviesList.clear() removes all the objects that was added to the list in a previous network request. Otherwise when user press top rated movies they would just show after popular movies in the Recyclerview. Finally using notifyDataSetChanged we notify the Recyclerview adapter that it's data has been changed and it needs to reload it's data. Mark as accepted if it worked. Cheers

Comment: Makes a lot  of sense now and I've Marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to make the url call again after the user clicks on the top rated option?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.most_popular:


        case R.id.top_rated:
            setTitle("TOP RATED");
            // return Top rated Movies list from API 
            parseMovieJSON();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```